# RoboGuice @Inject annotation works, but getInjector(this).getInstance() throws ConfigurationException

Tags: android, roboguice

On an Activity that derives from RoboActivity, I am able to add a member with an `@Inject` annotation that is populated after the call to `super.onCreate()` inside `onCreate()`; however, if I remove that field and attempt to retrieve the same type object from within a method, RoboGuice throws a `ConfigurationException`.

Example code that works:

```
public class MyActivity extends RoboActivity { 
    @Inject private MyType instance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // instance is set 
    }   
}
```

However, this example does not work:

```
public class MyActivity extends RoboActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        doStuffThatCalls_getMyType_Eventually();
    }

    protected MyType getMyType() {
        // Exception thrown here
        return RoboGuice
                .getInjector(this)
                .getInstance(MyType.class);
    }
}
```

Furthermore, if I add the field, then I am able to use `getInstance()` as before:

```
public class MyActivity extends RoboActivity {

    @Inject
    private MyType instance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        doStuffThatCalls_getMyType_Eventually();
    }

    protected MyType getMyType() {
        // This now works (of course, returns different instance of 'MyType')
        return RoboGuice
                .getInjector(this)
                .getInstance(MyType.class);
    }
}
```

I need to use the second example so that deriving classes can return a different instance of `MyType`, and don't want to leave the field as it may be wrongly used in the future.

How can I use RoboGuice like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a class is never injected via an annotation, RoboGuice considers the class to be not bound and ignores the binding.
To force the binding you need to use `superbind` instead of simple `bind` in your module:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        superbind(MyType.class).to(MyTypeImpl.class);
    }
}
```

Source: [RoboBlender wiki](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/RoboBlender-wiki#non-annotated-injections)